# What is the best way to add an OnClickListener to Endless ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity

What is the best way to add an OnClickListener to a ListActivity that's Endless?

I am using cwac-endless adapter for my endless list.

The problem I am encountering is only my first batch of data that populates the list get's the click listener. The new data that get's fetched doesn't get the onclick listener.

I've tried adding a onclick listener in the following manner.

I used ListActivity onListItemClick

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
String url = prodList.get(position).getProdUrl();
Log.i("URL",url);
Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(ProductListActivity.this, ProductWebView.class);
webViewIntent.putExtra("URL", url);
startActivity(webViewIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** Rookie mistake, the above code works fine, the problem was that I was referencing the original list that was passed in instead of referencing the list in my custom ArrayAdapter.